# AngularJS not updating view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm quite new to Angular, and I feel that the more nesting there needs to be, the more complex the code. I feel that I'm missing some fundamentals here.

Problem: In the chapter.html I see everything correctly, however, **when clicking the next hyperlink, the URL gets updated, the view does not.**

What am I missing, guys?

Here's my code:

**ChapterController.js**

```
app.controller('ChapterController', ['$scope', 'books', '$routeParams', function($scope, books, $routeParams) {
  books.success(function(data) {

    // Your code here
    $scope.book = data[$routeParams.bookId];
    $scope.chapter = data[$routeParams.chapterId];


    // If there no more chapters left, go back to the bookshelf view
    if($routeParams.chapterId >= $scope.book.chapters.length - 1) {
      $scope.nextChapterIndex = "#";
    }
  });

  // Using these properties to create the URLs in line 1 and line 11 of view/chapter.html
  $scope.currentBookIndex = parseInt($routeParams.bookId);
  $scope.currentChapterIndex = parseInt($routeParams.chapterId);
  $scope.nextChapterIndex = $scope.currentChapterIndex + 1;

}]);
```

**chapter.html**

```
<a class="button back" href="#/books/{{ currentBook }}">Back</a>
<div class="chapter" ng-repeat="chapter in book.chapters">
  <p><span class="title"> {{book.title}} </span> <span class="author"> {{book.author}} </span></p>
  <h2 class="chapter-title"> {{chapter.title}} </h2>

  <p ng-repeat="paragraph in chapter.paragraphs">{{ paragraph }}</p>

  <a class="button next" href="#/books/{{ currentBookIndex }}/chapters/{{ nextChapterIndex }}">Next</a>
</div>
```

**Route**

```
.when('/books/:bookId/chapters/:chapterId', {
    controller: 'ChapterController',
    templateUrl: 'views/chapter.html'
  })
```

Comment: if you check the network out does the browser say its grabbing chapter.html or is there an error or anything?

Comment: @TimCodes There seems no error. The URLs chapterId gets updated and the controllers IF block fires after a few clicks (when the paragraphs array ends)

Comment: log $scope.book and $scope.chapter to console and see if they are loaded when the controller loads

Comment: @TimCodes I'm working in Codecademy. It does use a server simulator browser in the exercises. Haha, I just scrolled the chapter.html and noticed that all the **paragraphs** are printed one after another already.